# use opencv dnn with multiple camera in same process

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm writting a program to detect object using OpenCV DNN with a pre-trained model like SSD Mobilenet or yolo v3.
I want to connect several cameras to my program and do object detection.

I don't know what is the best approach to this problem.
Can I have for example 20 threads which get frames from different cameras and each in turn give the frame to a single opencv dnn object to do detection (use queue to store frame to analyse) ?
OR
Can I instanciate 20 detection objects for each camera and do detection when frame is available. So potentially, I can have 20 detections at the same time.

Comment: It largely depends on your hardware I presume, if your GPU can handle loading the same net for 20 times (20 times the memory cost), sure... I don't know if there's any advanced libraries / packages available that can load "instances" of a network in a memory efficient way though. One possible approach would be to use the same process / thread, establish 20 camera connections and iterate through frames from each camera, feeding all frames to a single model, let's say your GPU can give you around 20 fps for a single camera feed, iterating through 20 camera feeds would give you 1 fps for each cam

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your answer. So, if my GPU can load 20 times the same net, I can run 20 detections at the same times, but I guess, 20 detections at the same time will take same time to do 20 detections in sequence ?

Comment: it's tricky to answer the first half of the question as (I presume) there must be other variables and not just simple arithmetics to load 20 nets and run object detection simultaneously. As for running 20 detections in sequence, take yolo-v3 320 for example, it can reach 45 fps (source https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/), this means every second, you can roughly "visit" each camera twice, i.e. 2 fps for each camera. However it would be a different story if you were on some sort of virtualisation and can expand horizontally (spin off multiple instances of your program)

Comment: I did some tests and I can not load 20 nets at same times. 
And in same thread/process in python, I can not manage 20 cameras in rtsp. I have some delay and some cameras crash because exceeding buffer.

i am searching a solution to do object detection to 20 cameras. Maybe the solution is to switch to C++ and do real multi threading. 

In python, multiprocessing is not good because transfert frame between process take to much time ...